# Проблема с добавлением даты в таблицу SQL?

Tags: php, sql

Всем привет. Есть проблема, УЖАСНАЯ ПРОБЛЕМА.
Существует таблица all_purchase. Есть поля с информацией и поле date с типом date (Дата).
Так вот получаю текущую дату в формате 17.03.2014. Записываю в переменную допустим $d. Тип данных ее String (незнаю на сколько это важно.)

Так вот вставляю стандартным способом данные через INSERT. Все проходит на ура но Дата добавляеться 20.03.2017 а должна 17.03.2014. ЧТО еще за прикол?))))) Выводил переменную $d через echo. Выводиться в нормальном виде 17.03.2014. Выводил и после insert тоже 17.03.2014 но записывается в таблицу 20.03.2017. Т.е. День тот же понедельник но год 2017.
Помогите, с ума схожу, ну или на крайняк как в Sql вставить текущую дату.?

Comment: приведите пример запроса, который вы выполняете, без подстановок переменных, т.е. именно то, что идет на MySQL севрер

Comment: Вставляю через codeignither. $this->db->insert('purchase',$purchase); 
Если знакома вам это система то поймете. С Уважением.

Comment: Судя по датам, очень похоже, что получаете дату в одном формате, а записывает в другом. Регулируется региональными настройками. С пхп не знаком, но это должно быть общее. Если присмотреться к вашим примерам, то дата 20.03.2017 , это 2017.03.20.
Очевидно, что от года взяли только первые два символа, а первую группу расширили до полного года.

Ищите описание региональных настроек сервера или используйте его формат при нанесении данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

не знаком конкретно с php, но предположу, что формат даты указан неверно (не в формате dd.mm.yyyy)